# Handling time zones in data mart/warehouse

Tags: sql-server, datetime, timezone, data-warehouse

We are starting to design the building blocks of a data mart/warehouse and we need to be able to support all time zones (our clients are from all over the world). From reading discussions online (and in books), a common solution seems to be to have a separate date and time dimension as well as a timestamp in the fact tables.

However, the question I am having hard time answering is what good does the date and time dimensions actually do for me considering my dynamic time zone requirements? A time dimension makes a little more sense but I'm having hard time with the date dimension. A general design approach for a date dimension usually includes properties such as day name, day of week, month name, etc. The problem I am having with all that is that 11:00 PM on Tuesday, December 31, 2013 in UTC is Wednesday, January 1st, 2014 in all time zones that are after UTC+2.

So if I will have to do all these time zone conversions on each and every query (and report) then what is the point of having and storing these properties that I will probably never use (seems like)? Some people suggest having fact rows for each time zone but that seems ridiculous to me. We need to be able to store millions of records each month.

Others suggest having a time zone bridge table which although makes some sense, it also seems like extra complexity and extra joins to accomplish something that my client apps and reports should easily be able to figure out from a date (reporting will be primarily web-based where there are a myriad of libraries to aide in converting, displaying and formatting dates).

The only thing I can think of is the ease and possibly performance of grouping by date and hour but how bad of a practice is to group by datepart (we're using MS SQL but we *will* be querying millions of rows) or should we consider just extremely simple date and time dimensions with not much more than hour, day, month and year numbers for the most part as most literals such as Monday wouldn't mean much when time zones come into play?

Comment: Excellent question for dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: You might also start with the recommendations in [this article](http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2005/11/01/handling-time-zones/) and then post to dba.se with questions or problems.

Comment: There are several similar questions on DBA; this one seems closest: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58762/data-warehouse-design-for-reporting-against-data-for-many-time-zones?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

To make such decision, you first need to determine what questions you would want to answer with the data in your data warehouse. Are facts meaningfully associated with the local time of the customers, local time of some central location (for example your company HQ), or can be associated with a date in an arbitrary timezone, say UTC? Do you even have information about the customer's timezone?

When two people from different time zones query your data warehouse, should they see exactly same results, or should the facts be reported as falling on the dates in the corresponding time zones?

For example, if you are reporting on people watching cable TV, the facts naturally fall into the local time zones because customers are located close to the cable headends. If you are reporting on customers watching content via Internet, you might be interested in the load of your servers, then it would be meaningful to report in the time zone where your servers are located.

Comment: We detect customer's time zone automatically and they can override it when viewing reports. They should be able to see the facts in their own time zone (or whatever time zone they choose) so they can easily optimize their campaigns but also they (as well as our accounting department) need to also be able to see how the facts look like in EDT since this is what they ultimately get paid on. So I need to be able to query, present and aggregate facts based on arbitrary time zone which I do know.

Comment: @VesselinObreshkov: At the first blush I would consider using a numeric value corresponding to the timestamp as a degenerate dimension. Maybe you can break the time/date dimension into time intervals, say 15 minutes long.